# How to download historical weather data from internet in xml or csv format for database?

Tags: xml, csv

I am working on data mining and I should get from the internet historical weather data from any weather station. The information I need should be daily weather data. Where can I get this information and download it because I have then to import it into database

Comment: See following webpage : http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/.  What programming language.  In VS (c# or vb.net) it is one instruction to download an xml file from a url.